# Why can the image not be viewed?

Tags: application, inventorship

In reference to the patent: [US20150183561](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150183561)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to ask Google. There are other sites viewing patents. [The Lens](https://www.lens.org) is one. Here is [US9493283B2](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_9493283_B2) (the associated patent to the cited application) on The Lens.